# How to hijack key combos in javascript?

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts

In Gmail, for example, when one presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, instead of it getting passed to the browser (which would normally bring up some sort of bookmark manager), it hijacks it for formatting purposes, i.e. turn on bold formatting for the message ur in the middle of comoposing.  Same for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>.

How is this done?

Comment: My answer would be PLEASE DON'T DO THIS... but I doubt that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, its not :)

Actually, what i'm planning on doing probably isn't as bad as you thought: i was going to use it for a greasemonkey script locally.

Comment: Can anyone please revert version 1?

Comment: What's the deal with the cat-like typing?

Comment: What the HELL happened to this question in the past few days?

Answer (score 9):

You would attach an `onkeydown` or `onkeyup` event handler to the global `document` object. For example, if I wanted to make the title bar change to "asdf" each time Ctrl-M was pressed, I would register the event handler through `window.onload`, like this:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    document.onkeydown = function(event)
    {
        var keyCode;
        
        if (window.event) // IE/Safari/Chrome/Firefox(?)
        {
            keyCode = event.keyCode;
        }
        else if (event.which) // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
        {
            keyCode = event.which;
        }

        var keyChar = String.fromCharCode(keyCode).toLowerCase();
        
        if (keyChar == "m" && event.ctrlKey)
        {
            document.title = "asdf";
            return false;  // To prevent normal minimizing command
        }
    };
};
```

W3Schools has more information on using these events: [`onkeydown`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp) and [`onkeyup`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp).

Also, I think I should note that there are some discrepancies across browsers in regards to the event properties (like, for example, in Firefox, you're supposed to access the keycode through `event.which`, while in IE it's `event.keyCode`, although Firefox may support `event.keycode`—confusing, isn't it?). Due to that, I'd recommend doing this stuff through a JavaScript framework, such as [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org) or [jQuery](http://jquery.com), as they take care of all the icky compatibility stuff for you.

Comment: Could you give an example please?

For (meta- (:P))example, show how to change the document's title to the text 'asdf' when the key combo CTRL+M is used.  Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: @asdf: Sure, I expanded my answer for you. Hope it helps.

Comment: @htw: yep, thanks alot :)

Now... You've got netscape/firefox/opera/ie covered, does that code account for safari/chrome as well?

Comment: @asdf: Yup. Oddly enough, I found that event.keyCode actually works in Firefox, for some reason, even though W3Schools says it shouldn't…weird. Either way, I still recommend that you should do this through either Prototype or jQuery: see dplante's answer for an example of how to do it in jQuery.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `preventDefault()` instead of `return false`?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the source for an HTML page that uses jQuery and does what [htw's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902407/how-to-hijack-key-combos-in-javascript/902490#902490) does.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hijack Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-1.2.1.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            document.title = "before keypress detected";
            $(document).keydown(function(event) {
                // alert('stuff happened: ' + msg + " " + event.keyCode);
                var keyChar = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();
                if (keyChar == "m" && event.ctrlKey) {
                    document.title = "ctrl-m pressed!";
                }
            });
         });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body id="body">
    <p>Change the path to jquery above as needed (search for ../scripts/jquery-1.2.1.js)</p>
    <p>Watch the title bar, then press control-M, then watch the title bar again!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onkeydown` or `onkeyup` event to fire a handler function:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.onkeydown = function(event) {
    var str = "";
    for (var prop in event) {
        str += prop + ": " + event[prop] + "<br>";
    }
    body.innerHTML = str;
};
```

With that you can see what properties an *event* object has.